# Fast username password matching from SQL database that has 50 million users

Tags: sql, select, query-optimization, where-clause

I am doing a research on how fast I can match username and passwords from my sql database.
I am looking how facebook/google/twitter can allow you to login in a matter of seconds, in a time they have millions and millions of uses.
What type of algorithm do they use? and why can they quickly identify that you have entered the right username password combination?
And why does the system quickly recognize that you have entered an incorrect password/username?
What is the method that they use?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would typically use a query like:

```
select 1 from users where username = ? and password = ?
```

Where the question marks represent the parameters to the query (you should probably use some hashing mechanism for the password). If the query returns something, then you know the credentials are OK. If no row is return, the login failed.

For performance, you just want an index on `users(username, password)`. Even with several millions of rows in the table this should be very fast, since the database can execute the query by looking at the index only.